# Unwanted white area next to html

Tags: html, css, web

When you make your screen smaller on this website http://www.webiaal.nl/ A white area will appear on the bottom and right side of the website. I don't how why. I already added this line in my CSS:

```
html,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  font-size:100%;
  font:inherit;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Can someone take a look at it?

Comment: Sorry..I tested it in chrome..there are no white spaces..which is the browser that you are using?

Comment: Firefox and Safari -- On chrome I get white spaces, but the white spaces will only show when you resize your screen to very small, a big white area will be shown in the bottom and right

Comment: I can confirm Chrome has white spaces too when resizing to smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I make a test on your site... Change the `padding to 1px` like `padding:1px;` It worked 100% no spaces!

Comment: I changed the code in my question to padding:1px; but I still see white spaces

Comment: Then the whole site is messed up and everything is going to the right, I don't think float:right is a solution for something.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is coming because the mission div is having a `width:300px` 
Because of which it is exceeding and taking the extra space

And also there is a

```
Padding:1px
```

Around every element, beacuse of which there is a 1px white space

Comment: I deleted the width, but still

Comment: Got the solution..in the bottom bar div there are two on which you have applied visiblilty:hidden.. Now hidden hides the div but they dont free the space taken by that div hence it was taking the space..Read how display:none works and visibilty:hidden works and then you will understand why the space was coming!!!!

Comment: This was crazy!!!! Use display: none to hide the div...even thogh you hav set the height of the div as 0 there were content in it..and due to how visibility works, it was never hidden, both the div text1 and text2 were taking their contents heights because of which the extra space was coming at the botttom...please respond if it works.

Comment: You're right, it is the bottom bar, but display: none; doesn't work. There is still a white space. I deleted the bottombar and the white space was gone, so the problem is with the bottom bar, only display none doesn't work. I uploaded the bottombar again but there is still a white space

Comment: Beacuse there is visibility right? Have you removed visibility? Remove visibility from every div there must br other div were you are might using the same

Comment: Now there is no space i cant watch any space in your website..please respond

Comment: everywhere, but now there is only a horizontal scroll bar when the screen is small but anymore when its the smallest

Comment: Give your body background as red and let me see where..beacuse i am viewing everything in mobile and i cant watch a white space!

Comment: I still cant watch it buddy...give me a snapshot

Comment: Look on your pc, because on your mobile you won't see any red space. But on a iPad for example you will see a red space. Try it on a small window with your pc

Comment: Header intern is having a paddingleft of 40px..thats causing a part of white space

Comment: And the rwst is because in the header inside the social div there is a tag at which you have applied again visibility!!!!

Comment: Please,check replace all your visibility:hidden by display:none!!! Else the problem will keeep on existing!!!!

Comment: I can see the extra spacing is because in social div you are still using visibility:hidden and also within the a tag ypu are still using visibility... Replace and acknowledg!

Comment: YOU ARE A HERO! it's perfect. Thank thank thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I can tell you, there will still be white space, remove the display none from social div, and you will see a white, that is because you are giving a margin-right:15px to the img tag used inside a...so u might also want to remove that

Answer (score -1):

I tested on Windows 8.1 Chrome and saw a horizontal scrollbar. You can try to change box-sizing:

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Just give height: auto once in * there is something wrong with the bottombar div

Comment: Got it!!! In your bottombar div there is div text1 there you have give visibilty:hidden, now hidden doesnt delete the elemnt it takes the space

Comment: yes but with the hidden I had this to:

#text1 {height: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;width: 0px;margin-right: 0px;visibility: hidden;}